# Correct HTML input type for a date limited to 7 days in the future?

Tags: html, validation

I need the user to be able to specify a date and time in the future, from the current date and time to 7 days in the future.

I thought that a date picker would not be the best way to do it, as many users will select dates before today or dates much more than 7 days in the future.

So what would be the best way?

My possible solution:

Should I create multiple spin boxes, a seperate one for: hour, minute, day, month, year as:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="31" step="1" value="12" required>
```

But then there is the problem of 30 vs 31 days in a month, leap years etc.

So does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using pure HTML puts the burden of validation on the browser.  Browser validation cannot be trusted.

If you want a rich UI experience that doesn't cause too much frustration for your users, I suggest using a datepicker widget, such as the one included in jQuery UI.  With the jQuery datepicker, you can limit the dates available to be selected.

See: [How to restrict date range of a jquery datepicker by giving two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537900/how-to-restrict-date-range-of-a-jquery-datepicker-by-giving-two-dates)

Comment: FYI, You will still need to do validation on the server side.

Comment: I have no doubt about that, I'm just trying to avoid user annoyance

Answer (score 0):

Use a date input with a limit to the max value.

```
<input type="date" min="2013-06-28" max="2013-07-04" required>
```

Even if not all browsers fully support date input you must validate on the server-side anyway. You can also show an error message next to the input if the user selects a date that's outside the limit.

Comment: Can you explain how will be able check whether it is 30 or 31 or 28 days?

Comment: That's the problem though, the users will primarily be using internet explorer

Comment: @user1671639:  You don't have to worry about the number of days in a month.  the input type of "date" is used to enter a full date (month, date, and year).  The browser handles how that is done.  Although this is new in html5, so only newer browsers support it, and then not all browsers support it fully.

Comment: @StevieG Then it's either a custom JavaScript datepicker or dynamic validation as the users type/select the date.

Comment: @scott.korin Thanks for the info.  I didn't know about the feature in `type="date"`.  Once again thanks.