# jQuery UI Datepicker - Hide previous navigation arrow for a specific month

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a simple angular code that opens the jQuery datepicker with a future date (within an angular directive):

```
            scope.StartDate = $filter('date')(scope.BillingDate,'MM/dd/yyyy');
            $('#rangeFromSelect').datepicker({maxDate: new Date("10/10/2020")}); // this fires up the datepicker correctly
```

If scope.BillingDate = 06/12/2018 it shows up the datepicker correctly, but I wish to hide any days before that particular date. My approach to hide the previous navigation works when I do the following:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-prev').hide();
```

This works OK until I press the next month and get back to the previous month (ie, the previous navigation button shows up again).

Is there anyway to hide the arrow for that specific month? Or is there a way I could completely disable the dates before the date I mentioned here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537900/how-to-restrict-date-range-of-a-jquery-datepicker-by-giving-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly but could you use the Min Date Option?

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```