# How to disable the dates after the current week on datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am creating a datepicker that will only allow you to select a date in a current week 48 hours after the current date.

I've already created the datepicker that will start the select date after 48 hours of the current date.

```
var hours = 1728e5;
  var minDate = new Date(Date.now() + hours); 
  minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
  var datepick = $(".datepicker");
  datepick.datepicker('setDate', "");
  datepick.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
```

I expect to have a datepicker that will only select a date in the current week after 48 hours from the current date. So dates before the current date after 48 hours and dates after current week should be disabled.

Comment: So.......what's your question?

Comment: How to disable the dates after current week.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict date range of a jquery datepicker by giving two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537900/how-to-restrict-date-range-of-a-jquery-datepicker-by-giving-two-dates)

Comment: Nope it's different. My code above is already working. However, I am thinking to tweak my code a little bit to also make the dates after the current week be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1: with Moment.js

An implementation with moment.js is going to render the most accurate results with the fewest lines of code. From there, just plug in the number of remaining days as a maxDate:

```html
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

```
// get number of days remaining in the week with moment.js
// the number 6 represents Saturday, our last day of the week
var daysTillWeekOver = 6 - moment().day();

// set max date variable
var dateMax = `+${daysTillWeekOver}d`;

// set min date variable
var hours = 1728e5;
var dateMin = new Date(Date.now() + hours); 
dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate());

// activate datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: dateMin,
  maxDate: dateMax
});
```

Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/grantnoe/pen/byaxEM

Moment.js: https://momentjs.com

jQuery UI Datepicker maxDate: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

## Solution 2: without Moment.js

If you're against using moment.js, there's this (less "guaranteed") method:

```js
var date = new Date();
var weekday = date.getDay();
var remainder = 6 - weekday;
document.getElementById("remainder").innerHTML = remainder;
```

```html
<p>There are <span id="remainder"></span> days remaining in the week, not including today.</p>
```

**If you use this method, your javascript looks like this:**

```
// get number of days remaining in the week
var date = new Date();
var weekday = date.getDay();
var daysTillWeekOver = 6 - weekday;

// set max date variable
var dateMax = `+${daysTillWeekOver}d`;

// set min date variable
var hours = 1728e5;
var dateMin = new Date(Date.now() + hours); 
dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate());

// activate datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: dateMin,
  maxDate: dateMax
});
```

Comment: Thank you, This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, what if I want the start date can be selected is next week onwards regardless of the day of the current week?

Comment: @JuliusTicong I'm not sure what you mean. Use May 23 as an example: what days would you have be available in the datepicker?

Comment: The available date should start on May 27(first day of next week). Regardless of what date in the current week the available date should always start next week.

Comment: If you want the week to start on Monday, change the 6 to a 7 on ``daysTillWeekOver`` like this: ``var daysTillWeekOver = 7 - weekday;``. Then set ``minDate`` to ``dateMax`` in the datepicker options to bump the beginning date forward to the start of next week. I'd remove or change the value of the ``maxDate`` option then, because it's calculating a max that will be one day prior to your min, which will break things.

Comment: Thank you @Grant Noe it works as I want it to be. Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Grant Noe, hope you don't mind to ask for your help with another tweak on the datepicker, with the code above is it possible we can make a condition that if the day of the current week falls on a Friday or Saturday the dates on the calendar will be disabled? So instead enabling the next week's dates it will be disabled.

Comment: @JuliusTicong totally. After you set up the dateMin, set a new variable: ``var weekdayCheck = dateMin.getDay();`` I'm assuming you want to run this on the min date rather than today's date. Then just run a conditional: ``if (weekdayCheck == 5 || weekdayCheck == 6) {}`` Inside of the if statement (which would confirm dateMin is Friday or Saturday), just set ``dateMin = dateMax;`` to disable all the dates. You might need to add a day to dateMax to get it to overlap, but I'm not sure. You can play with it.